# Testing an impure function

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing

As part of an online programming course ([6.00.1x](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-computer-science-mitx-6-00-1x-5)), I'm asked ([Quiz p8](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:MITx+6.00.1x_7+3T2015/courseware/19136f9d4de045fdab0ce099230f5385/af94467328b74ed38f0e901460166d70/)) to create a function, `satisfiesF(L)`, that filters `L` in-place using `f`, then returns the length of `L`.

- `f` is a function defined for me that returns `True` for items that should remain in the list
- The remaining list items should be in the same order as before

I've written 2 solutions to this problem, tested them, and submitted them, but both were rejected. No reason was provided, as the problem is designed to test our ability to come up with our own test cases. For this reason, **please do not provide working code**, but rather give me a general idea of what's going wrong. I see 3 main possibilities at the moment:

- I have misunderstood the problem
- I made a subtle programming mistake
- edX made a mistake with their test cases *(unlikely)*

Here are my 2 solutions:

```
def satisfiesF(L):
    L[:] = [i for i in L if f(i)]
    return len(L)
```

```
def satisfiesF(L):
    i = 0
    while len(L) > i:
        if f(L[i]): i += 1
        else: L.pop(i)
    return len(L)
```

Here is the full description of the problem verbatim:

> Write a Python function called `satisfiesF` that has the specification
>   below. Then make the function call `run_satisfiesF(L, satisfiesF)`. Your
>   code should look like:
>
> ```
> def satisfiesF(L):
>     """
>     Assumes L is a list of strings
>     Assume function f is already defined for you and it maps a string to a Boolean
>     Mutates L such that it contains all of the strings, s, originally in L such
>             that f(s) returns True, and no other elements. Remaining elements in L
>             should be in the same order.
>     Returns the length of L after mutation
>     """
>     # Your function implementation here
>
> run_satisfiesF(L, satisfiesF)
> ```
>
> For your own testing of `satisfiesF`, for example, see the following test function `f` and test code:
>
> ```
> def f(s):
>     return 'a' in s
>
> L = ['a', 'b', 'a']
> print satisfiesF(L)
> print L
> ```
>
> Should print:
>
> ```
> 2
> ['a', 'a']
> ```
>
> Paste your entire function `satisfiesF`, including the definition, in the box below. After you define your function, make a function call to `run_satisfiesF(L, satisfiesF)`. Do not define `f` or `run_satisfiesF`. Do not leave any debugging print statements.
>
> For this question, you will not be able to see the test cases we run. This problem will test your ability to come up with your own test cases.

And, for the sake of completeness, here are my latest set of tests (I'm using [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html)):

```
>>> L = ['bat', 'cat', 'dog', 'elephant']
>>> satisfiesF(L) == len([i for i in L if f(i)])
True
>>> [i for i in L if not f(i)]
[]
>>> L = ['ab', 'b', 'ac']
>>> satisfiesF(L)
2
>>> L
['ab', 'ac']
>>> L = ['a', 'a', 'b']
>>> satisfiesF(L)
2
>>> L
['a', 'a']
>>> L = ['a', 'a', 'a']
>>> satisfiesF(L)
3
>>> L
['a', 'a', 'a']
>>> L = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
>>> satisfiesF(L)
1
>>> L
['a']
```

These tests use `def f(s): return 'a' in s` as suggested in the problem. I haven't tested with other functions for `f`, but I don't think that would affect the outcome.

I've tried replacing `satisfiesF(L)` with `run_satisfiesF(L, satisfiesF)`, but the tests still pass.

---

[Other questions about 6.00.1x Quiz p8](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=satisfiesF)

---

Proof that I'm not crazy:

[image: answer to Quiz p8 marked incorrect]

Comment: You appear to have written `satisfiesL`, not `satisfiesF`.

Comment: Thankyou @jonrsharpe, tobias_k. These were errors copying the code to StackOverflow and do not appear in the original code or in the code I submitted to edX. I've corrected them now.

Comment: Both of your formulations pass the tests and meet the spec. Note that we cannot see the exercise without registering - perhaps you should raise this matter on the course forum? Have you included the line `run_satisfiesF(L, satisfiesF)` in your submission, correctly indented?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: The forum is closed to prevent people “accidentally” posting working code. Thanks for taking a look at it though — I'm glad it's not just me who can't figure out what's wrong with this.

Comment: Why the close votes? How is the problem too broad? Is it because nobody can find any errors in the code, or because I'm asking for hints? I'm just looking for something like: “Have another look at the part of the spec that says “Remaining elements in L should be in the same order.””

Comment: Is the docstring provided in the description required?

Comment: Eeeuh, I tested your two answers, and they both check out `CORRECT`

Comment: Agghh. I sent edX an email, and they replied saying there was an indent error. I eventually realized that I'd indented `run_satisfiesF(L, satisfiesF)` by 1 space. >.< Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant reproduce your problem:

Second:

[image]

First also checks out.

And the one I was thinking about:

```
for i in range(len(L)-1,-1,-1):
    if f(L[i]) != True:
        del(L[i])
return len(L)
```

Also checks out.

Comment: WTF? o.O That's exactly what I entered ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mvodz.png)). The only difference is the comment. I guess edX just hates me.

Comment: Maybe just some mixed tab/spaces indentation or some sever glitch. I find these quizzes check out best if you just copy your working code entirely from your ide/text editor.

Comment: Yeah. The error was a single space before `run_satisfiesF(L, satisfiesF)` >.< Sorry for wasting your time.